# Make an integration test of the dbContext

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, asp.net-core-3.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to do an integration test to test if my ApplicationDbContext is working properly. It is on a MVC core asp.net 3.1 application using entity framework and Pomelo.EntityFramework.MySql.

For the moment, I have just created the MVC application with ApplicationDbContext; An entity ; and I configured the database in startup.cs. At that time, I tested to migrate and update the database and it works.

After that, I added 2 projects in my solution for the unit test and the integration test, then adding the project reference on them. I did a simple test to use ApplicationDbContext but it doesn't work and I'm having trouble solving this problem.

**If anyone has an idea on how to create this kind of test using xunit.**

My project code is here: https://github.com/BeRoots/aspnetcore3.1-MVC-EF-MySQL

The integration test that I tryed to do is [HERE](https://github.com/BeRoots/aspnetcore3.1-MVC-EF-MySQL/blob/master/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/UnitTest2.Pomelo.EntityFramework.Core.MySql.ApplicationDbContextTest.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to add the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` NuGet package to your `weblab2` and `XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2` projects.

Then you need to reference your `weblab2` project from your `XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2` project.

Your project will now compile, but your test will still fail.

Finally, you will need to setup your `ApplicationDbContext` instance, before using it.
I did this in form of a very simple example for the `Application_DbContext_Should_Connect_To_MySql_Database` test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Application_DbContext_Should_Connect_To_MySql_Database()
{
    // Arrange
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .UseMySql("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=so59888273", builder => builder
            .ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18), ServerType.MySql));

    ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    bool expected = true;

    // Act
    bool result = dbContext.Database.CanConnect();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

Here is a patch containing all the changes:

```
diff --git a/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/UnitTest2.Pomelo.EntityFramework.Core.MySql.ApplicationDbContextTest.cs b/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/UnitTest2.Pomelo.EntityFramework.Core.MySql.ApplicationDbContextTest.cs
index 2c60ea3..0b058a5 100644
--- a/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/UnitTest2.Pomelo.EntityFramework.Core.MySql.ApplicationDbContextTest.cs
+++ b/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/UnitTest2.Pomelo.EntityFramework.Core.MySql.ApplicationDbContextTest.cs
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 ï»¿using System;
+using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
+using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
 using weblab2.Data;
 using Xunit;

@@ -6,18 +8,24 @@ namespace XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2
 {
     public class UnitTest2_Pomelo_EntityFramework_Core_MySql_ApplicationDbContextTest
     {
-        [Fact]
-        public void Application_DbContext_Should_Connect_To_MySql_Database()
-        {
-            // Arrange
-            ApplicationDbContext DbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
-            bool expected = true;
-            // Act
-            bool result = DbContext.Database.CanConnect();
+[Fact]
+public void Application_DbContext_Should_Connect_To_MySql_Database()
+{
+    // Arrange
+    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
+        .UseMySql("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=so59888273", builder => builder
+            .ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18), ServerType.MySql));

-            // Assert
-            Assert.Equal(expected, result);
-        }
+    ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
+    bool expected = true;
+    
+    // Act
+    bool result = dbContext.Database.CanConnect();
+
+    // Assert
+    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
+}
+        
         [Fact]
         public async void Application_DbContext_Should_Connect_To_MySql_Database_Async()
         {
diff --git a/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2.csproj b/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2.csproj
index a2352e4..665815c 100644
--- a/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2.csproj
+++ b/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2/XUnitIntegrationTestWeblab2.csproj
@@ -8,9 +8,14 @@

   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.0.1" />
   </ItemGroup>

+  <ItemGroup>
+    <ProjectReference Include="..\weblab2\weblab2.csproj" />
+  </ItemGroup>
+
 </Project>
diff --git a/weblab2/weblab2.csproj b/weblab2/weblab2.csproj
index 0fcc948..6a736ad 100644
--- a/weblab2/weblab2.csproj
+++ b/weblab2/weblab2.csproj
@@ -4,6 +4,10 @@
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

+  <ItemGroup>
+    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.1" />
+  </ItemGroup>
+


 </Project>
```